# Wordpress text color on buttons

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble changing the text color on the buttons on a WordPress website. I suppose I need a code that will change the text color on the buttons. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, your question is to broad.  What you are asking might be able just by changing the css of your theme, with a different theme or plugins.  Do you have any knowledge in php, javascript, html and css?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
1.) to change the color with the customizer

2.) to add custom your css in the customizer with (appearance - customize - additional css)

```
.button.green{
background-color: #colortag;
color: #colortag
```